# linq compare 2 list

Tags: linq, compare

```
var companytoexclude = from c in db.Companies
                   from p in c.Projects
                   where p.ProjectEndDate == null
                   select c;

var list = from m in db.Members.Include("Companies.Projects.Experiences")
                     where m.MemberId == id
                     select m;
```

how do I exclude companies that are in companytoexclude in list?

Member have many company 
company have many project 
project have many experiences

K I kind of solved it.
So what I did is just add in

```
   foreach (Company c in companytoexclude )
            {
                list .First().Companies.Remove(c);
            }
```

so is there a easier to show this?
I want the member with list of companies, not just companies.

some data

```
Member
MemberId    Name
2011        Jet

Company
CompanyId   MemberId    CompanyName
18          2011            Company1
29          2011            Company2

ProjectId   CompanyId   ProjectName ProjectEndDate
1           29          Project1    2008-08-01 00:00:00.000
2           29          Project2    2009-08-01 00:00:00.000
3           18          Project3        NULL
```

now I want it to return everything but company1 and project3

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var list = from m in db.Members.Include("Companies.Projects.Experiences")
           where m.MemberId == id
           where !m.Companies.Intersect(companiesToExclude).Any()
           select m;
```

That will only return members which don't include *any* companies which you're trying to exclude.

Mind you, given that you're specifying a MemberId, I'd pretty much only expect one result anyway... it's unclear what you're trying to do.

If you want all the companies from that single member *except* the companies to exclude, it's easy:

```
var member = db.Members.Include("Companies.Projects.Experiences")
               .Single(m => m.MemberId == id);
var companies = member.Companies.Except(companiesToExclude);
```

If that's not what you're after, please clarify your question.

Also note that your `companiesToExclude` query may well not be right to start with. Are you trying to exclude all companies with *any* project with a null end date? If so, you want:

```
var companiesToExclude = db.Companies
                           .Where(c => c.Projects
                                        .Any(p => p.ProjectEndDate == null))
```

Comment: where !m.Companies.Intersect(companiesToExclude).Any() keep returning nothing

Comment: @Prez: Well then maybe all your members have companies which are excluded... if you could give some sample data which is failing, that would help.